# How to edit this code?

Tags: python

The following code will take a list of names and a list of greetings and combine them so one greeting will be applied with one name in the order of their index. Such as we say “hi susan”, “hola juan”, and so forth.

1.) How do I revise the following code so that I can store those in the greetings list for a future greeting for that individual and print the combined greeting list?

```
# Implemented as a While Loop.
names_list = ['susan', 'juan', 'wolfgang', 'piere', 'aednat']
greetings_list = ['hi', 'hola', 'tag', 'salut', 'haigh']
idx = 0
while idx < len(names_list):
    greetings_list[idx] = greetings_list[idx] + " " + names_list[idx]
    idx = idx + 1
print(greetings_list)
```

2.) How do I rewrite this code to use a for loop instead of the while loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel)

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. You should show us what you have tried tovsolve the problems so far.

Answer (score 0):

**Use `zip` to iterate over both lists simultaneously** (provided the lists are of the same length and items of the same index are related - as in this case):

```
names_list = ['susan', 'juan', 'wolfgang', 'piere', 'aednat']
greetings_list = ['hi', 'hola', 'tag', 'salut', 'haigh']

for greeting, name in zip(greetings_list, names_list):
    print("%s %s" % (greeting, name))
```

Comment: Ok so it would look like this?:                                                      names_list = ['susan', 'juan', 'wolfgang', 'piere', 'aednat']
greetings_list = ['hi', 'hola', 'tag', 'salut', 'haigh']
for name, greeting in zip(names_list, greetings_list):
    print("%s %s" % (name, greeting))
print(greetings_list)

Comment: Because the output I am getting is                                                     susan hi
juan hola
wolfgang tag
piere salut
aednat haigh
['hi', 'hola', 'tag', 'salut', 'haigh']

Comment: @Dirk, I believe so - although, I'm curious: why are you outputting `greetings_list`? Given your use of it in the first comment, it seems like you want to update that list - is that correct?

Comment: I want an output saying  “hi susan”, “hola juan”, and so
forth. But I'm not getting that output.

Comment: @Dirk: Ah, I see! Edited. The above code should provide the result you seek.

Comment: To clarify, `zip` creates an aggregate iterator from several iterable objects - i.e. it's not limited to 2 lists, one can use many if need be.

Comment: Thank you! That's very close to the desired solution, but it should be in a list form. Right now it's outputting like this:                                              hi susan
hola juan
tag wolfgang
salut piere
haigh aednat
                                                                                                                                             Instead I want it to be like hi Susan, hello Juan, etc.

Comment: @Dirk: Hmm... Surely you can do this yourself, yes? It's not too difficult, all things considered. From what you've commented, it appears you understand very little Python at all. While there's nothing wrong with that since we all were beginners once, for me to continue on in such manner would rob you of the incredibly rewarding experience of learning and problem-solving. Otherwise, as-is, we're essentially doing what seems to be homework for you. (Not that I'm saying that you are doing this, but unless you can show otherwise from your own attempts, this is the extent of what I'll do.)

Comment: Ok,  would I use the dictionary function to create a list?

Comment: I appreciate if you would help me, and in the process I am learning.

Comment: @Dirk: If you used a dictionary function, you'll create a dictionary - that's not what you want. You want a list, so use a list - hint: you've created a couple in your first program.

Comment: Ok so would I use greetings_list = greetings_list+ " " + names_list

Comment: @Dirk: No, that will never work as they are incompatible types. For more help, please see: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list

Answer (score 0):

You can store combined list by zipping the two list contents in a new list .

```
combined_list = [ [greeting, name] for name,greeting in zip(names_list,greetings_list)]
```

Then , as needed you can iterate through it

```
>>> for i in combined_list:
    ' '.join(i)

'hi susan'
'hola juan'
'tag wolfgang'
'salut piere'
'haigh aednat'
```

Comment: Hi, the output you gave me comes close to the desired solution. Thank you! But it's printing out like this: [['hi', 'susan'], ['hola', 'juan'], ['tag', 'wolfgang'], ['salut', 'piere'], ['haigh', 'aednat']]                                                                                Is there a way to get rid of the brackets?

Comment: Here is my code that I put in:                                                      names_list = ['susan', 'juan', 'wolfgang', 'piere', 'aednat']
greetings_list = ['hi', 'hola', 'tag', 'salut', 'haigh']
idx = 0
combined_list = [ [greeting, name] for name,greeting in zip(names_list,greetings_list)]
for i in combined_list:
    ' '.join(i)
print(combined_list)

Comment: you are printing combined list. print this: for i in combined_list:
    print ' '.join(i)

Comment: Did that solved the problem? If yes then do you mind accepting the answer to close the loop.